# Best way to allow complete API access between applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, oauth, doorkeeper

I have two rails applications A & B running on two separate servers, and I want to define an API with which A can make requests to B and potentially other applications down the line. What I have done is use doorkeeper to implement the oauth client credentials grant type. Is this the right way to go here? I feel like this is a weird case, because oauth is usually used to sign in a specific user and allow data from them to be transmitted between applications. What I am doing is simply using client credentials grant flow to get an access token when the application boots up then using that forever or until the app restarts. Is there a better way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far using client credentials grant type has worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

When faced with this decision, I ended up just rolling my own. It's not that much work to put together the API key models and authentication logic. Sometimes I find it more difficult to implement a gem, which is often a bit of a Swiss army knife (trying to do a whole lot of things), when I can just bang it out myself.